# How to bundle "express" node.js application? (with Webpack)

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm trying to bundle a node.js express application into single file for distribution to remove servers. I am trying to use webpack for such purposes. The bundling process works fine, but when I try to run the app from the bundle I am getting the error:

> **Error: secure random number generation not supported by this browser
>   use chrome, FireFox or Internet Explorer 11**"

Below is my webpack config. I am running the code with `node bundle.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    './index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'null-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'null-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true)
  ]
}
```

Here is a full error stack:

```
    Error: secure random number generation not supported by this browser
use chrome, FireFox or Internet Explorer 11
    at module.exports (webpack:///./~/crypto-browserify/rng.js?:21:13)
    at exports.randomBytes (webpack:///./~/crypto-browserify/index.js?:22:23)
    at _rng (webpack:///./~/node-uuid/uuid.js?:60:53)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/node-uuid/uuid.js?:121:20)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///./~/node-uuid/uuid.js?:272:3)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/node-uuid/uuid.js?:274:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tomi/Github/apps/react-app-test/server/bundle.js:545:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/tomi/Github/apps/react-app-test/server/bundle.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./~/graphql-tools/dist/mock.js?:18:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tomi/Github/apps/react-app-test/server/bundle.js:341:2)
```

Comment: I've not done this with WebPack, but I've done it with Browserify (a long time ago). The bundle seems to include the Browserify modules (like `crypto-browserify`) that mimic the built-in Node modules. Whereas, you want the built-in ones. How you manage that in WebPack, I don't know, but that's the problem. There is a WebPack/Node-related post [here](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) that might help.

Comment: I tried also browserify and the result was the same unfortunately ;/ I don't know how to force those modules to load from node.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I cannot remember. I will have a poke around, later, to see what I'd done. Unfortunately, it was a while ago - but I can remember doing stuff with Browserify to avoid bundling built-ins and binary modules.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure @tomitrescak has already found the answer to this question from 4 years ago... but, for anybody else stumbling here - there is one option missing in the *webpack* config:

```js
  ...
  target: 'node',
  ...
```

Hope, this will help somebody...

Answer (score 1):

Late in the game but the fact that `crypto` is replaced by the browser substitute is the reason why the build is failing. I solved this issue with browserify by simply excluding that module from the build since the intent is to run it with NodeJS, the crypto module will just be required as expected:

```
browserify index.js --exclude crypto  -o build.js
```

For Webpack, excluding crypto should also work then.